# Two Methods for Multiple Activites

Tags: java, android

Hi i have two methods:

```
public void saveTxtFile(Context context, String name)
{

    File path = context.getApplicationContext().getFilesDir();
    try
    {
        FileOutputStream writer = new FileOutputStream(new File(path,name));
        writer.write(items.toString().getBytes());
        writer.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void loadContent(Context context, String name)
{
    File path = context.getApplicationContext().getFilesDir();
    File readForm = new File(path, name);

    byte[] content = new byte[(int) readForm.length()];

    FileInputStream stream = null;
    try
    {
        stream = new FileInputStream(readForm);
        stream.read(content);

        String s = new String(content);
        s = s.substring(1, s.length() - 1);
        String split[] = s.split(", ");

        // There may be no items in the grocery list.
        if (split[0].isEmpty())
        {
            items = new ArrayList<>();

        }
        else
        {
            items = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(split));

        }


    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I have multiple activites(Activity_1, Activity_2... Activity_50 etc) with same txt values to save....
when i put them directly(methods) in every class its working, but i need write one HelperClass?
where i not to duplicate the code and save values throug one method for all activities.
Im thinking right?

Comment: Are you asking if you should write two functions and then use the same functions across all activities? If that's the question then the answer is probably yes.

Comment: That's right, but if i put saveTxtFile(); in seperate class its working, but until i dont exit from activity, then override previously data and add new.... and when i add loadContent(); in this same seperate class, saving only once and nothing i can't add anymore until i delete txt file. And all is repeat (add values-->save-->exit-->enter-->values is there, but new content don't add